# NSColorWell doesn't open when bound with ValueTransformer

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nscolor

I have an `NSColorWell`, which is bound to a property that contains an `NSString` instance, which get's transformed into an `NSColor` through my ColorTransformer (`NSValueTransformer`). It essentially transforms something like `#FF0000` into an `NSColor`. This works as expected, but the ColorWell no longer opens it's Pane when clicked. When I disable the binding, it works again. Any clues to what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

return YES in

`+(BOOL)allowsReverseTransformation`

the apple docs example has it return NO, however the default implementation has it return YES. The reasoning behind this is in theory simple enough: apple doesn't want your users to be able to set a color which will then crash the app (being that a reverse transform was not implemented).  You should then probably implement

```
- (id)reverseTransformedValue:(id)value
```

to make sure this doesn't happen, if you haven't done so already. (If you don't apple's docs say it will call - (id)transformedValue:(id)value)

Comment: Kind of worked for me :) I'm handling everything inside of transformedValue based on a type check of value, but I guess I can use reverseTransformedValue in this case.